# remove option from second select if already selected in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two select input to select years (years,years_1) , when i change years to 2020 i want to remove 2020 from years_1 but when i change years to 2021 then in years_1 2020 must add back and 2021 will remove (or disable also work).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const yearsArray = [];
    for (let i = currentYear; i > currentYear - 3; i--) {
      yearsArray.push(i.toString());
      yearsArray.sort();
    }
    setYears(yearsArray);
    setYears_1(yearsArray);
    setCommonYear(yearsArray);
  }, []);
```

there setYears,setYears_1,setCommonYear are useStates to store year array.

```
if (years !== null && years_1 !== null) {
      if (years.includes(value)) {
        setYears_1((prevState) => prevState.filter((item) => item !== value));
      } else {
        setYears_1(commonYear);
      }
    }
```

this is what i have tried

```
                            <select
                            name="year"
                            value={turnoverModels?.year}
                            onChange={handleChangeTurnoverYear}
                            
                          >
                            <option value="NA" selected>
                              NA
                            </option>
                            {years.map((item) => (
                              <option key={item} value={item}>
                                {item}
                              </option>
                            ))}
                          </select>
                          <select
                            name="year"
                            value={turnoverModels?.year}
                            onChange={handleChangeTurnoverYear}
                            
                          >
                            <option value="NA" selected>
                              NA
                            </option>
                            {years_1.map((item) => (
                              <option key={item} value={item}>
                                {item}
                              </option>
                            ))}
                          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added state to store the values of both the `select` dropdowns. Then we can use the `useEffect()` hook to find when the value of first select changes and update the `years_1` array.

**Demo :** [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/72313064-r8v3e2?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [years, setYears] = useState([]);
  const [years_1, setYears_1] = useState([]);
  const [select1, setSelect1] = useState(null);
  const [select2, setSelect2] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const yearsArray = getYears();
    setYears(yearsArray);
    setYears_1(yearsArray);
  }, []);

  // When the first year changes, update the years_1 array
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!select1) return;
    const filtered = getYears().filter((y) => y !== select1);
    setYears_1(filtered);
  }, [select1, years_1]);

  const getYears = () => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const yearsArray = [];
    for (let i = currentYear; i > currentYear - 3; i--) {
      yearsArray.push(i.toString());
      yearsArray.sort();
    }
    return yearsArray;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        name="year"
        value={select1}
        onChange={(e) => setSelect1(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="NA" selected>
          NA
        </option>
        {years.map((item) => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <select
        name="year"
        value={select2}
        onChange={(e) => setSelect2(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="NA" selected>
          NA
        </option>
        {years_1.map((item) => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setYears_1` again when select in `years` array:

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-sky-hbm8ec?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [years, setYears] = useState([]);
  const [years_1, setYears_1] = useState([]);
  const [select1, setSelect1] = useState(null);
  const [select2, setSelect2] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const yearsArray = getYears();
    setYears(yearsArray);
    setYears_1(yearsArray);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!select1) return;
    const filtered = getYears().filter((y) => y !== select1);
    setYears_1(filtered);
  }, [select1, years_1]);

  const getYears = () => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const yearsArray = [];
    for (let i = currentYear; i > currentYear - 3; i--) {
      yearsArray.push(i.toString());
      yearsArray.sort();
    }
    return yearsArray;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        name="year"
        value={select1}
        onChange={(e) => setSelect1(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="NA" selected>
          NA
        </option>
        {years.map((item) => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <select
        name="year"
        value={select2}
        onChange={(e) => setSelect2(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="NA" selected>
          NA
        </option>
        {years_1.map((item) => (
          <option key={item} value={item}>
            {item}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```